# How to analyse the time complexity of the following code?

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

Is it `O(n^6)` or `O(n!)`?

```
public boolean isScramble(String s1, String s2) { 
    return isScramble(s1, 0, s1.length(), s2, 0); 
} 

private static boolean isScramble(String s1, int begin1, int end1,
                                  String s2, int begin2) { 
    final int length = end1 - begin1; 
    final int end2 = begin2 + length; 

    if (length == 1) return s1.charAt(begin1) == s2.charAt(begin2); 

    for (int i = 1; i < length; ++i) 
        if ((isScramble(s1, begin1, begin1 + i, s2, begin2) && 
             isScramble(s1, begin1 + i, end1, s2, begin2 + i)
            ) || 
            (isScramble(s1, begin1, begin1 + i, s2, end2 - i) && 
             isScramble(s1, begin1 + i, end1, s2, begin2))) 
           return true; 

    return false; 
}
```

Analysis:

```
T(1) = 1
T(n) = (T(1) + T(n-1)) * 2 + (T(2) + T(n-2)) * 2 + ....
     =~ T(1) + T(2) + ... + T(n-1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
private static int ord = 1;

public boolean isScramble(String s1, String s2) { 
    boolean b = isScramble(s1, 0, s1.length(), s2, 0);
    System.out.println("The order is: " + [insert your classname here].ord);
    return b;
}

private static boolean isScramble(String s1, int begin1, int end1, String s2, int begin2) { 
ord++;
final int length = end1 - begin1;
```

Then run it with increasing sizes (n) of string and make a note of how ord increases with n.  That'll give you the correct O notation.  Basically you just count how many times your recursive function gets called.